# How to modify registry properties, or are there any other properties act as "global variables"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am finding solutions related to properties that act as "global variables". I need to store the response of first service call (e.g. OAuth access token), then in the second sevice call, the grant access token action can be skiped by using filter to check if the access token is still valid and ready to use. The solution may looks like the init.xml of Salesforce.com connector (Already login to xxx...), however, the requirement is not to use the "class" mediator, which may result in a difficulty of management.

As a result, I am thinking about if the properties saved in registry can help, however I cannot find enough documentation related to "update" properties in registry, or registry scope.

I am new to WSO2esb and stackoverflow and I would appreciate any of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the property mediator to set properties in the registry scope. But you can achieve the same requirement using dbreport and dblookup mediators. You can save the token in a database using dbreport mediator and retrieve that using dblookup mediator. This is one possible way to achieve your requirement without using a class mediator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't use dbreport and dblookup mediators before. I am not sure but before the use of those mediator, should I install some database like MySQL or Oracle? I think I am looking for a way use ESB only, and that's why the class mediator is not suitable.

Comment: You can actually use the internal H2 database coming with the ESB since this is a small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a Proxy Service for service chaining , and inside that proxy , you can set properties which are available throughout the proxy flow.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Property+Mediator

Comment: I know that properties can be usedd through the proxy flow, however, I want to know if there is a way to store properties for next use. It is like, the proxy service can filter the "grant Oauth token" action if the token is not expired. Besides, the Oauth token is granted from another web service API. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Ok but in your question you say   "I need to store the response of first service call (e.g. OAuth access token), then in the second sevice call..." So are these service calls synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: I think that should be asynchronous. The OAuth access token will be valid for 10 mins, and all calls invoked during this time will not process the "grant access token" activity. Sorry for the delay of reply, it is a little hard to do this in China (the damn great wall)